# Web service for iPhone app to allow image uploads

Tags: ios, image-upload

I am using Symfony 1.4 to build a web app that allows photo sharing. I have also written a REST API for the iPhone app to communicate with the web app. At present, the API returns JSON response for request by iPhone app. I am now required to allow the iPhone app to upload photos. What I am unable to figure out is how will the API get and save uploaded image data from the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can base64 encode the image as a text field in the json transaction

Answer (score 2):

Images from iphone uploaded are encoded and decoded using Base64.